# Changing the standard pwa installation notification

Tags: javascript, css, web, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to change the style of the "add to home screen" notification for pwa?

Or can you turn it off and use your notification component?
Settings for pwa I use standard.

[image: pwa]

Answer (score 3):

You can catch the `beforeinstallprompt` event and use it to show custom Install prompts.

```
let deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  // Prevent the mini-infobar from appearing on mobile
  e.preventDefault();
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;
  // Update UI notify the user they can install the PWA
  showInstallPromotion();
});
```

- https://web.dev/customize-install/